# C++ - Brent-Pollard rho algorithm infinite loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, factorization

I have this following function. I got it from two sites and tried to adapt it into my own but it didn't work very well.

When I test `unsigned long int max - 2` or to but it as a number `4294967293` it puts the following code into an infinite loop where `ys` will keep coming back to the same value.

I am very new to factorisation algorithms and step by step help into why I am getting the infinite loop would be great.

The following code is just my "rho" function. I have another function called `gdc` which is the same as every other `gdc` recursive function out there.

```
unsigned long int rho(unsigned long int n) 
{
    if (n == 1) return n;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return 2;

    unsigned long int y = rand() % n;
    unsigned long int x;
    unsigned long long int ys = y;
    unsigned long int c;
    do
        c = rand() % n;
    while (c == 0 || c == n - 2);
    unsigned long int m = 1000;
    unsigned long int d = 1;
    unsigned long int q = 1;
    unsigned long int r = 1;
    while (d == 1)
    {
        x = y;
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
        {
            y = y * y % n;
            y += c;
            if (y < c)
                y += (std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() - n) + 1;
            y %= n;
        }
        int j = 0;
        while (j < r && d == 1)
        {
            ys = y;
            for (int i = 0; i < m && i < (r-j); i++)
            {
                y = y * y % n;
                y += c;
                if (y < c)
                    y += (std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() - n) + 1;
                y %= n;
                q *= ((x>y) ? x - y : y - x) % n;
            }
            d = gcd(q, n);
            j += m;
        }
        r *= 2;
    }
    if (d == n)
    {
        do
        {
            ys = ys * ys % n;
            std::cout << ys << std::endl;
            ys += c;
            if (ys < c)
                ys += (std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max() - n) + 1;
            ys %= n;
            d = gcd( ((x>ys) ? x - ys : ys - x) , n);
        } while (d == 1);
    }
    return d;
}
```

The examples I adapted my code from :

- [Brent-Pollard ρ factorisation](http://xn--2-umb.com/09/12/brent-pollard-rho-factorisation)
- [Pollard Rho Brent Integer Factorization](https://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2010/09/18/pollard-rho-brent-integer-factorization/)

### EDIT

I have done as Amd has suggested and tidied up my code and moved repetitive lines into helper functions. However I am still getting an infinite loop for the `d==n` part near the bottom. For some reason, `f(ys)` ends up essentially returning the same thing that it had returned earlier so it keeps cycling through a series of values.

```
uint64_t rho(uint64_t n)
{
    if (n == 1) return n;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return 2;

    uint64_t y = rand() % n;
    uint64_t x;
    unsigned long long int ys = y;
    uint64_t c;
    do c = rand() % n; while (c == 0 || c == n - 2);
    uint64_t m = 1000;
    uint64_t d = 1;
    uint64_t q = 1;
    uint64_t r = 1;
    do 
    {
        x = y;
        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++)
            y = f(y, c, n);

        int j = 0;
        do 
        {
            ys = y;
            for (int i = 0; i <= min(m, r-j); i++)
            {
                y = f(y, c, n);
                q *= (abs(x,y) % n);
            }
            d = gcd(q, n);
            j += m;
        } while (j < r && d == 1);
        r *= 2;
    } while (d == 1);
    if (d == n)
    {
        do
        {
            ys = f(ys, c, n);
            d = gcd(abs(x, ys), n);
        } while (d == 1);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Naive expressions such as `y * y % n` do not compute modulo `n` if `n` is sufficiently high, other than that the code is a bit long to seriously check

Comment: Well I can compute max unsigned long int just fine.  It's just max unsigned long - 2 that fails so it's definitely not that

Comment: It may accidentally work. That doesn't make it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should always terminate.  By the time you get to that point in the algorithm, `x` will be within the cycle (since `y` started at `x` and went all the way around to detect the cycle using Brent's cycle detection). The value `ys` started at `y` which started at  `x`, so it will also continue around the cycle and eventually meet up with `x` again (see Floyd or Tortoise and Hare cycle detection).  At this point you will have `gcd(ys,x)==x`, and that final loop will terminate.

There are several bugs in the posted implementation which I believe may be causing the issue:

```
x = y;
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)                // should be strictly less than
    ...

    ys = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < min(m, r-j); i++)  // again, strictly less than
    {
        y = f(y, c, n);
        q = (q*abs(x,y)) % n;  // needs "mod" operator AFTER multiplication
    }
    ...
```

You can also replace the initialization of `c` with

```
uint64_t c = (rand() % (n-3))+1
```

if you want a number in the range [1,n-3].

Here's the original paper by Richard P. Brent: [An Improved Monte-Carlo Factorization Algorithm](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb051i.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
this works for me, and not trapped inside infinite loop:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdint.h>

#define min(a,b) (a<b?a:b)
#define abs(x,y) (x > y? x - y : y - x)

uint64_t gcd(uint64_t m, uint64_t n) {
    while (true) {
        int r = m % n;
        if (r == 0) {
            return n;
        }
        m = n;
        n = r;
    }
}
uint64_t f(uint64_t y, uint64_t c, uint64_t n) {
    y = (y * y) % n;
    y += c;
    if (y < c)
        y += (std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() - n) + 1;
    y %= n;
    return y;
}

uint64_t rho(uint64_t n)
{
    if (n == 1) return n;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return 2;

    uint64_t y = rand() % n;
    uint64_t x;
    uint64_t ys = y;
    uint64_t c;
    do c = rand() % n; while (c == 0 || c == n - 2);
    uint64_t m = 1000;
    uint64_t d = 1;
    uint64_t q = 1;
    uint64_t r = 1;
    do
    {
        x = y;
        for (int i = 0; i <= r; i++)
            y = f(y, c, n);

        int j = 0;
        do
        {
            ys = y;
            for (int i = 0; i <= min(m, r - j); i++)
            {
                y = f(y, c, n);
                q *= (abs(x, y) % n);
            }
            d = gcd(q, n);
            j += m;
        } while (j < r && d == 1);
        r *= 2;
    } while (d == 1);
    if (d == n)
    {
        do
        {
            ys = f(ys, c, n);
            d = gcd(abs(x, ys), n);
        } while (d == 1);
    }
    return d;
}
int main() {
    std::cout << rho(std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() - 2) << "\n";     //9241
}
```

**Old:**
according to an improved monte carlo factorization algorithm: http://wwwmaths.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb051i.pdf
pp:182-183
error:   ys = x * x % n;
correct: ys = ys * ys % n; // ys=f(ys)

please use uint32_t or uint64_t ... from stdint.h for good and clean coding style:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdint.h>

int gcd(int m, int n) {
    while (true) {
        int r = m % n;
        if (r == 0) {
            return n;
        }
        m = n;
        n = r;
    }
}

#define min(a,b) (a<b?a:b)
#define abs(x,y) (x > y? x - y : y - x) 

uint32_t f(uint32_t y, uint32_t c, uint32_t n) {
    y = (y * y) % n;
    y += c;
    if (y < c)
        y += (std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max() - n) + 1;
    y %= n;
    return y;
}

//http://wwwmaths.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb051i.pdf
//pp:182-183
uint32_t rho(uint32_t n) {
    if (n == 1) return n;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return 2;

    uint32_t y = rand() % n; // y = x0
    uint32_t x;
    uint64_t ys = y;
    uint32_t c;
    do { c = rand() % n; } while (c == 0 || c == n - 2);
    uint32_t m = 1000;
    uint32_t d = 1;
    uint32_t q = 1;
    uint32_t r = 1;
    do
    {
        x = y;
        for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++)  y = f(y, c, n);
        int j = 0;
        do
        {
            ys = y;
            for (int i = 1; i <= min(m, r - j); i++)
            {
                y = f(y, c, n);
                q = q * abs(x, y) % n;
            }
            d = gcd(q, n);
            j += m;
        } while (j < r && d == 1);
        r *= 2;
    } while (d == 1);
    if (d == n)
    {
        do
        {
            ys = f(ys, c, n);//not:     ys = f(x,c,n);      
            d = gcd(abs(x, ys), n);
        } while (d == 1);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Cheers for this, however that's what I had in my code. I had ys instead of x to begin with and in another post I saw that they used x so I tried it. Either way I still get infinite loops

Comment: I recommend clean your code first (like using some helper functions like f(x)  and recommendations as above(it will help to find bugs), then try to debug the infinite loop to find the exit strategy from infinite loop, if you had still problem feel free to post your new code.

Comment: Just added an edit. I have found what is causing it but I don't really understand why